# Cannot find open shared object file libjli.so -- no such file or directory

Tags: java, redhat

On 64-bit RHEL5 running Java 1.6.0 update 16, root can successfully run a Java program but a user can't because `libjli.so` supposedly can't be found. SELinux is turned off and the environment is the same before the program is run. I've tried putting `libjli.so` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it doesn't make a difference.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first possibility that springs to mind is that `libjli.so` is readable only by root.  So step one:

```
ls -l $(locate libjli.so)
```

If it's in an odd location (not in `/usr/lib` or `/lib`) create the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` containing the path to the directory containing `libjli.so` and run `/sbin/ldconfig` as root.

For more troubleshooting info, run this command, once as root and once as a non-root user:

```
ldd java
```

In a sane world, the output of the two would be identical.  How they differ should tell you a lot about why this is failing.

Comment: Sheesh, I had set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I thought ldconfig's conf would be fruitless. ldd java returns a relative path containing '..' for libjli, I guess that didn't work out as the packagers hoped for this particular Java 1.6.0 update 16 FCS client.